# How i join a group of my classmates?

Tags: lifespan

I'm 18 and I was an Introvert for the first year of my engineering life with very few friends and with some enemies say X abs Y. X is a guy who was one of my close friends who slapped me for some reason and I slapped back, he's not talking to me from that time(8-9months). Y was my best friend in the beginning the first year. Then we drifted apart, he became a good friend with X, then we stopped talking because I acted like a jerk. Then I spoke with Y, we're fine now. But X is still not talking to me.

Now I'm in 2nd year and I've tried to change a lot, I talk to a lot of people now, I've a lot of friends and I hangout with comparably more no. of friends now. But in our class I've a group of 15 (10b and 5g) classmates who are very friendly with each other and stay together all the time having fun and talking a lot. I've always wanted to join them and have fun but I screwed in the beginning as I said. But now I badly wanna join them and have fun with them. I don't know how, they're perfect together and the group is pretty large already. I'm afraid of rejection and it'll be awkward for the rest of my engineering life to walk around them. :(. Help me people, please. All I want now is to join them :/ nothing more, I've no reason to liveas I've lost interest in life. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Go to X and say something like, "You know I was thinking back and I was a real idiot last year. I was going through a bad patch. I'm sorry I over-reacted/flipped/behaved badly. Let me buy you a beer and I'll feel better about it." Better still, buy a round.

Comment: Dude I've apologized a lot of times, he doesn't seem to care at all. He's a total jerk. But no, I don't hate him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop over-thinking it and just join them.  You have a common interest already in that you are all at the same institution, just join in the conversation.

My grandfather gave me some advice which always seems to work.  Listen to a conversation where a number of people are all talking about the same thing.  They will all have their own view point.  If you weight everything up and then, when there is a gap in the conversation, jump in with a fairly short comment that basically summarizes what everyone had just been talking about, typically everyone will agree and some even say "Oh yes, that's exactly the point I was making."  Don't say too much :-)

Remember, if someone seems to have a problem with you; it's their problem.  Everybody wants to be liked and have friends, everybody worries about it, some realize sooner than others that you just need to get involved.

Don't get hung up in what happened in the past because, no matter how much you think on it, you can't do anything about it other than learn from it.

Good luck and remember; be bold.